# auto select dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a category dropdown. When user select any category from a dropdown and then second dropdown will appear.. It will show a list of product that is related to a category (via jQuery ajax).

When user click any entry from a product dropdown it will redirect to same page but with the `GET` query..

For example:

```
page.php?category=3&product=6
```

When user on that page, how to auto select the category dropdown and product dropdown?

```
  <label>Category</label>
     <select id="category">
       <option value="0">Please select a category</option>
        <?php
           $SQL = "SELECT * FROM category";
           $query = mysql_query($SQL);
           while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
              echo "<option value='{$cat['id']}'>{$cat['name']}</option>";
             }
         ?>
     </select>
     <select id="product"> </select>

    $("#category").change(function() {
        var category =  $(this).val();
        $('#product').append($("<option></option>").attr("value","0").text("Please Select Product"));
        $.getJSON(host + "/ajax_select_product.php?categoryid=" + category, function(data) {
            $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                $('#product').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data[index].id).text(data[index].name));
            });
        });
    });

​
    $("#product").change(function() {
        var product = $("#product :selected").val()
        var category =  $("#category :selected").val()
        window.location = "page.php?category=" + category + "?product=" + product;
    });
```

Comment: @Coder category and product dropdowns should be auto selected when the page.php redirect to `page.php?category=x&product=x`

Comment: Auto-selected to which value ?

Comment: What do you mean which value? Value could be anything depending what user select from a dropdown.. For example you select "Apple" from a category and second dropdown will show via ajax..  from a product dropdown you select "Ipad" and then it will redirect to `page.php?category=x&product=x` - it should remember what you have selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with following;

```
<label>Category</label>
     <select id="category">
       <option value="0">Please select a category</option>
        <?php
        $currentCategory = 0;
        $curretProduct =0;

        if (!empty($_GET['category'])) {
            $currentCategory = $_GET['category'];   
        }

        if (!empty($_GET['product'])) {
            $currentProduct = $_GET['product']; 
        }
           $SQL = "SELECT * FROM category";
           $query = mysql_query($SQL);
           while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
              if ($cat['id'] == $currentCategory) {
                echo "<option value='{$cat['id']}' selected=\"selected\">{$cat['name']}</option>";
              } else {
                echo "<option value='{$cat['id']}'>{$cat['name']}</option>";
              }
             }
         ?>
     </select>
     <select id="product"> </select>
    var currentProduct = "<?php echo $currentProduct; ?>";
    $("#category").change(function() {
        var category =  $(this).val();
        $('#product').append($("<option></option>").attr("value","0").text("Please Select Product"));
        $.getJSON(host + "/ajax_select_product.php?categoryid=" + category, function(data) {
            $.each (data, function (index, element) {
                if (data[index].id == currentProduct) {
                    $('#product').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data[index].id).attr("selected", "selected").text(data[index].name));
                } else {
                    $('#product').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data[index].id).text(data[index].name));
                }

            });
        });
    });

​
    $("#product").change(function() {
        var product = $("#product :selected").text()
        var category =  $("#category :selected").text()
        window.location = "page.php?category=" + category + "?product=" + product;
    });
```

Comment: You must check null control of product and category. You can set javascript variable by using php value.After that you can check it in products iteration in javascript side.

Comment: Thanks for example. Javascript code will be in seperate file though. I guess I will need to put 'var currentProduct = "<?php echo $currentProduct; ?>";' in the page.php file

Comment: you can put a javascript function on body onload.Forexample; <body onload="selectProduct(currentProduct);"> This function will call your implementation you wrote above with currentProduct parameter.Or like you said, you can declare global javascript variable currentProduct = "<?php echo $currentProduct; ?>"; at the top of page.php and you can use it in your following js files

Comment: What about adding hidden input tag? When it redirect to next page - it will add product ID in the hidden tag and javascript will try to find it.

Comment: Sure, you can use it in that way. You will put it in hidden field like <input type="hidden" name="current-product" id="current-product "value="<?php echo $currentProduct;?>"/>   and you can get current product by using $("#current-product").val(). And note that you need to do null check. if ($("#current-product")) {var currentProduct = $("#current-product").val();}

Comment: I've got auto select for category working but it does not execute it for product dropdown entries though.

Comment: Did you put javascript function in separate file?how did you use it?

Comment: I've added '$("#category").change();' which did a trick. It will execute product dropdown when the page reload.

Comment: Is there any function in change event?

Comment: Yes there is the one I have provided in my question but remember when the page reload and auto select the category... the product dropdown will not get executed unless you change the category manually.

Comment: You can put your function to document.ready and your function will use current product category. This is the solution